# How to install the development version of the app without removing the published version?

Tags: android

I've made quite a few changes to my app, and I want to see if there are any crashes if the users update my app to the new version from the previous version. I want download my app from play store, perform some actions, and then update it to the development version, but when I try to do so, Android Studio promopts me to uninstall the old version first. Is there a way I can update over the old version, just like my users would, if I published an update?

Answer (score 1):

```
android {
  // other stuff here

  buildTypes {
    debug {
      applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
    }
  }
}
```

This will give your `debug` builds a distinct application ID, allowing you to have the `debug` and `release` builds installed at the same time.

Note, though, that otherwise the two apps will be identical in all other respects by default, meaning that you will have two identical launcher icons. To distinguish between those, you might consider adding `app/src/debug/res/values/string.xml` and have a debug definition of the `app_name` string resource, so your launcher icons will have different captions. Note that this recipe assumes that you have a conventional Android Studio project (`app/` module, with the manifest using `@string/app_name` for relevant `android:label` attributes).

Comment: Will I be able to access the data of the release version from the debug version of the app?

Comment: @stack: Not unless that data is in a common location on external storage. From Android's standpoint, they are separate apps. Moreover, you **really** want to be using a separate copy of data, so that your debug build does not screw up your release build's data.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is, all my files were on the internal storage, but on the next update, I want to copy them all to the external storage, delete it from the internal storage, and then display it within my app. How do I go about doing this if I can't access the data folder of the release version from my debug version?

Comment: @stack: Off the cuff? Install the debug edition, then try manually copying the files from the release internal storage into the debug internal storage, to then be able to test your real data migration. I worry about file permissions, though.

Comment: Alternatively, is there anyway I can publish an update to the play store as draft, and only I be able to access it, until I publish it to the users? I somehow need to simulate an update.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll have to root my phone after all.

Comment: @stack: "is there anyway I can publish an update to the play store as draft, and only I be able to access it, until I publish it to the users?" -- possibly, but that's outside my area of expertise, sorry.